Approximating the matrix logarithm sum $\ln(A+B)$ for "small $B$" in the non-commutative case
I am currently trying to solve a larger problem in gauge theory that involves a term of the form $$\ln(A+B)$$ I want to approximate this expression such that it has a form similar to $$\ln(A)+X+O(B^2)$$ for some $X$.
Specifically, I have $A\in G$, where $G$ is some arbitrary unitary matrix group, and $B=-i[\lambda,A]\in G$ where $\lambda$ is a "small" element of the Lie algebra. In general, the group is not commutative, which has rendered my attempts using various power series and binomial expansions unfruitful.
I need only to find a first-order approximation for this expression. I obviously cannot make any reality assumptions on the eigenvalues either, which has limited my ability to use certain integral expressions. Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

can you write $A=UDU^{-1}$ with a diagonal $D$?

For unitary matrices the logarithm is not necessarily uniquely defined. Take for instance A = (1+i)/sqrt(2) and B = 0. What is the logarithm of this 1x1 matrix?

You could use the Daleckii-Krein Theorem, e.g. see this post.

Note the following interesting formula for the derivative of the matrix logarithm :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \ln(A+tB) = \int_0^\infty (A+sI)^{-1}B(A+sI)^{-1} \,\mathrm{d}s,
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are independent of the parameter $t$. Then, integrate on the interval $[0,1]$ in order to get
$$
\ln(A+B) - \ln(A) = \int_0^\infty (A+sI)^{-1}B(A+sI)^{-1} \,\mathrm{d}s
$$
